# Visual Studio: Unresolved Token Error while linking CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I cannot link the [CreateILockBytesOnHGlobal()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method in my Visual Studio project. I get an unresolved token error while linking. My project is a plain Windows Forms Project. Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is said in the table at the bottom of the page, you should link with the `Ole32.lib` library. Add it to Linker + Input + Additional Dependencies setting.